# WordPress : Change name in my button from 'LOGOUT' to the name of the user?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

On my WordPress site I have a modal button in the header that allows users to login. Once logged in the button text changes from 'LOGIN' to 'LOGOUT', giving the user the ability to logout if they want to. How can I get that button to show the users name instead of 'LOGOUT'. For example my name is Tina and when I first select the login button & login successfully the header shows 'LOGOUT' but I want it to show 'TINA' instead. Thanks for the help in advance!

HTML:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <a class="login_button" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a class="login_button" id="show_login" href="">Login</a>
<?php } ?>

<form id="login" action="login" method="post">
    <h1><img src="image.png" class="login-logo" width="80" height="auto"></h1>
    <p class="status"></p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
    <a class="lost" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>">Forgotten your password?<br><br></a>
    <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
    <a class="close" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: change the value property put the variable you use to hold their username in the middle. e.g. value="<?php $username ?>"

Comment: I've just added a little bit of code at the top. In reference to your answer do you mean where is says <a class="login_button" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a> ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm developing it into a dropdown menu after where the logout button would be an option in the dropdown menu

Comment: Ok, in answer to your question, this should tell you everything you need to know https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: Note: From a UI perspective, I'd personally still include Logout but also include the name. So for instance "Logout Tina". Otherwise it looks like a random link at the top of the page that doesn't tell the user what's happening.

Comment: If you were to read a little bit before commenting you'll be able to see I've already said that I'm converting it to a dropdown menu reason why I don't want it to say logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_current_user()` built-in function provided by wordpress, as per the following code-snippet, function will return the current logged in user information object:

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'User first name:' . $current_user->user_firstname;
    echo 'User last name:' . $current_user->user_lastname;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to achieve your expectations:

I hope you should have been stored username in session if not, please store logged-in user name in the session.

> i.e: $_SESSION['username']='ABC'; //Store your username in session when you will Log-In to the site.

```
  <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $logout = $_SESSION['username'] ? $_SESSION['username'] : "Logout";
  ?>
  <a class="login_button" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>"> <?php echo $logout; ?> </a>
  <?php } else { ?>
        <a class="login_button" id="show_login" href="">Login</a>
  <?php } ?>
```

try this, it will work for you.